# How to deal with passing a parent object as an argument?

Tags: c#

I am unsure of whether what I am doing is completely invalid or merely poor practice, but I have a class, let's call it `Bar`, which is a field of some parent class, let's call `Foo`, and one of `Bar`'s methods requires that I pass the instance of the parent `Foo` as an argument. This seems like a terrible and messy idea, but I can't think of a better way to do it. `Foo` effectively stores a number of `List<Bar>`, `Bar`, `ConcurrentDictionary<string,Bar>`, or similar and is used to allow me to build up all of my `Bar` instances without a duplication of data.

The principle of the code is something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar1> bar1List {get;set;}
    public List<Bar2> bar2List {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Bar
{
    //EDITED TO IMPROVE EXAMPLE
    public int Value {get;set;}
    public void DoSomething(Foo parentFoo)
        {
        }
}

public class Bar1 : Bar
{
    public override void DoSomething(Foo parentFoo)
        {
        //EDITED TO GIVE AN EXAMPLE OF DoSomething()
            this.Value = this.Value + parentFoo.bar2List[0].Value:
        }
}

public class Bar2 : Bar
{
    public override void DoSomething(Foo parentFoo)
        {
        //some other code
        }
}

Foo foo = new Foo()
//populate foo somehow

foo.bar1List[0].DoSomething(foo);
//this is what looks very odd to me and feels kind of like a circular reference. The code will never be circular in that if I want to change bar1List within DoSomething() I will do it by "this", not foo.bar1List.
```

I thought about making each `List<BarX>` (where X is a number) a static field of `BarX` but this doesn't work as everything is multithreaded and I would want multiple instances of `List<BarX>`; I thought about accessing the parent object using the standard methods but I don't see how that doesn't get messy if I have two parents for one `List<BarX>`. Any ideas/hints? I don't want to move the `DoSomething` method out of `Bar`.

EDIT FOR DESCRIPTION OF ACTUAL PROBLEM:
As mentioned before, `Foo` functions as a repository of all of the various `Bar` instances; all of the `Bar` instances are interweaved so `Bar1` might contain a `List<Bar>`. One family of `Bar`s, for example `List<Bar1>` is prescribed as the program input; the rest of the `BarX` Lists, etc etc are then created from this List, as the required, using a wholo load of config files and logic. There are, in total, 9 flavours of `Bar`, arranged in a non-linear manner e.g. my first `Bar1` instance might require a `Bar7` instance, which in turn requires another `Bar1` instance (which wasn't present in the initial `List<Bar1>`) and so on. Each `BarX` flavour has a `Generate()` method which takes the place of `DoSomething()` to determine how to build it. This arrangement lends itself to thread very nicely, hence the need for a Concurrent place to hold all of these instances, where the basic idea is IfExists, return it and assign to field/List/whatever; otherwise build it and add it to the `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: You could implement your `LIst<Bar>` as `IList<Bar>` and use an `ObservableCollection<Bar>`, while adding a property called `Parent` to `Bar` of type `Foo`. Each time and item gets added or removed, the observable collection fires a `INotifyCollectionChanged` event, and you can set/unset the `Parent` property of `Bar` to the `Foo` (`this`) variable?

Comment: It depends on what `DoSomething` does with that parent object. In general, if it's only using a few properties, you probably should pass those properties as parameters to `DoSomething`. But if it needs to call methods on the parent, you can pass them as delegates or you can pass the parent. There are many ways to notify a parent of things changing in a child. Without more information about what `DoSomething` does, it's difficult to give recommendations.

Comment: This does indeed look "wrong" but since we have no idea what `DoSomething` is doing with `foo` there's no way to suggest anything... it would be much more useful if you described the *actual* scenario instead of arbitrary classes.

Comment: I'm with @AntP here, this is a typical X-Y problem, you're trying to find a solution for another problem. Could you describe, what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: See if this explains your problem - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/261453/what-is-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-childs-reference-to-its-parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways you could achieve such a thing, is by implementing an `ObservableCollection` for your `Foo` class to listen to changes inside the list, and upon adding / removing items, you could add the parent to the child Bar item.

Like this, your method doesn't have to reference the parent, but it can access it over the Property `Parent` which would be of type `Foo`.

Since they would all reference the same instance of `Foo` inside on `Foo` instance, you wouldn't have duplication of data.

As an example of such an implementation, you could do it like this

First define an interface that offers easy access to a Parent property

```
public interface IChild<T>
{
    T Parent { get; }
}
```

And we could do the same for the DoSomething method of Bar

```
public interface IBar
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

And the implement the two interfaces inside an Abstract version of Bar, leaving the DoSomething method abstract

```
public abstract class Bar : IChild<Foo>, IBar
{
    private Foo parent;
    public Foo Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return parent;
        }
        set
        {
            parent = value;
        }
    }

    public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

and implementing the 2 versions of Bar, like for example:

```
public class Bar1 : Bar
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        if (this.Parent == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parent cannot be null");
        }
        // code against parent
        Console.WriteLine("Bar 1 doing something");
    }
}

public class Bar2 : Bar
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        if (this.Parent == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parent cannot be null");
        }
        // code against parent
        Console.WriteLine("Bar 2 doing something");
    }
}
```

Then, you need to make some changes to your `Foo` class still, that registers itself to the collection (Bar1Collection, Bar2Collection) and that offers a way to listen to the changes in the collection. It also implements the `IDisposable` interface so that we can unregister from the CollectionChanged events at the moment we no longer need the Foo class

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IList<Bar> bar1Collection = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();
    public IList<Bar> Bar1Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return bar1Collection;
        }
    }

    private readonly IList<Bar> bar2Collection = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();
    public IList<Bar> Bar2Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return bar2Collection;
        }
    }

    protected void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
            {
                if (item is Bar)
                {
                    var bar = item as Bar;
                    bar.Parent = null;
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                if (item is Bar)
                {
                    var bar = item as Bar;
                    bar.Parent = this;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void RegisterCollection(INotifyCollectionChanged collection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        collection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    protected void UnregisterCollection(INotifyCollectionChanged collection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        collection.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        RegisterCollection(Bar1Collection as INotifyCollectionChanged);
        RegisterCollection(Bar2Collection as INotifyCollectionChanged);
    }

    private bool isDisposed = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing || isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }
        isDisposed = true;
        UnregisterCollection(Bar1Collection as INotifyCollectionChanged);
        UnregisterCollection(Bar2Collection as INotifyCollectionChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
}
```

As a test method, this console program could then run against it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BarFoo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo foo1 = new Foo();
            Bar bar1 = new Bar1();
            Bar bar2 = new Bar2();
            foo1.Bar1Collection.Add(bar1);
            foo1.Bar2Collection.Add(bar2);
            Debug.Assert(bar1.Parent != null);
            Debug.Assert(bar2.Parent != null);
            bar1.DoSomething();
            bar2.DoSomething();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
            foo1.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```